# Windows Server 2003 to provide DHCP to devices

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, dhcp, licensing

I will use  Windows Server 2003 to provide DHCP to devices like printers and other embedded device. Is it true that I need to buy a license ? Some one say to me that I need to buy call licenses for each client .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should have windows CALs(Client Access Licenses) when you have a server and clients in your network.

You can refer to the following link

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/licensing/about-licensing/client-access-license.aspx

Comment: Are you sure about this ? Typically, you need a CAL for anything that will authenticate with the server (directly or through AD) but not for anonymous services like DHCP and DNS.

Comment: Indeed I will use an anonimous DHCP,  my clients are embedded devices linux based, (no windows client, no AD and no RDP AD.) In the article is not clear about this.